# error installation on other pc (video player)

Tags: .net, com, installation

I made a simple video player, and build it as installer project. the thing is, it worked perfectly on my pc, but when i try to run it on other pc it give me an error.

[image]

i just know that, the other pc doesn't have `vlc player`. and when i try to download the `vlc` it worked perfectly fine. how do i resolve this ? if i try to install it in clients side (more than 5 w/o download and install the `vlc player`)

as for the target cpu, iam already setting it as `x86` and my pc is 64 bit
[image]

while in installer process it give this warning
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a COM error.  It is because the COM library you reference is not installed on the target PC.  It works on your PC because the COM library is installed on your PC.

The only way it will work is if you install the target COM library as part of your installation process.

Comment: how to resolve this ? `The only way it will work is if you install the target COM library as part of your installation process.` i don't get it

Comment: Did you use DirectShow or Media Foundation to play the video?  If so, these libraries need to be installed on the target PC.

Comment: neither, iam using the `vlc player` just like this tutorial `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWE-lGgdzss`

Comment: The embedded player in the video uses VLC COM.  This COM is installed when VLC Player is installed.  So, your application will only work on machines that have VLC Player installed.  You have two options to fix this - you can manually install VLC Player whenever you install your application, or, if you want it to happen automatically as part of your installation, have a look at Bootstrapper https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx.

Comment: thanks for your information. how do you know that? (need to install manually) because i thought i need to register it via cmd like "REGSVR 32 "C:..\axvlc.dll" or maybe modify the axvlc.dll registration type to "self registeration / vsdrfCOMSelfReg" at the installer setting, but i stil can't managed it because it give me an error. see update

Comment: Try following these instructions to determine why the dll is not registering - https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages